# while compile the "models.py", error like :django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, virtualenv

here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\jm\\Desktop\\learning_log\\ll_env\\Lib\\site-packages")
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text
```

This is the error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Have you made an attempt to fix the issue yourself?  What issues have you run into?  What OS are you using?  Presumably some version of Windows.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. So what is your setting for the env. variable?